# Django: Generate models from database vs database from models

Tags: python, mysql, django, django-models, code-generation

I'm getting myself acquainted with MVC by making a 'for-fun' site in django. I'm really liking a lot of the features of the api and python itself. But one thing I really didn't like was that django encourages you to let it build your database FOR you. I'm well aware of inspectDB and I'm interested in using it.

So my question is this, is there any solid reason that I should choose one method of model/DB generation over another? I feel far more comfortable defining my database in the traditional SQL way (where I have access to combined keys). But I'm concerned using things that aren't available through the Model api may cause problems for me later on. Such as combined keys, medium_text, etc.

I'm using mysql btw.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're starting a new project, always let Django generate the tables. Django provides mechanisms to use a pre-existing database to support legacy data or situations where you aren't in direct control of the database structure. This is a nice feature of Django for those who *need* it, but it creates more work for the developer and breaks many conventions in Django.

You still can, and in fact are encouraged to, add additional indexes and any other database-specific optimizations available to you *after the fact*.

Comment: Thanks, this has been nagging me ever since I saw that it does the table creation for me...

Comment: Hope you don't mind if I post follow up questions here. 

Are there things I shouldn't do, even AFTER django builds the database?

Comment: Not that I can think of short of altering the actual structure of the table or column types or properties -- basically anything that that would actually break the symmetry between the table and your model. But adding indexes and such is completely safe.

Comment: yeah, so how do you do it?